# How to print or extract the text in the div class with any <p> <span> or etc. using BeautifulSoup and Python3.x?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, window

Suppose I have a text in div class like this `<div class="col span-3">Name</div>`. I try but failed to get.
I need to extract the **Name** follow by text that is in the class col span-9.
Here Is my code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://v2.sherpa.ac.uk/id/publisher/1939?template=romeo"

r = requests.get(url)
htmlContent = r.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlContent, 'html.parser')
title = soup.title
print(title)

div_text = soup.find("div", {"class": "col span-3"}).get_text()
div_text = soup.find("div", {"class": "col span-9"}).get_text()
print(div_text)
```

When I use `div_text = soup.find("div", {"class": "col span-3"})` `print(div_text)` this then I give the result with all the tag. but When I use .get_text() then it give only first tag name.
when I use both col span-3 and col span-9 with getting text then it gives the text that has class span-9.

It gives only one result as "1066 Tidsskrift for historie [English]" not the heading and that result is from class col span-9. I need like this" Name: 1066 Tidsskrift for historie [English]; URL: http://www.universitypress.dk/shop/1066-tidsskrift-for-73c1.html; Country: Denmark; Number of Publications: 1"

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the div_text when you assign to it a second time. Try something like this:

```
div_text_header = soup.find("div", {"class": "col span-3"}).get_text()
div_text_value = soup.find("div", {"class": "col span-9"}).get_text()
print(div_text_header)
print(div_text_value)
```

For the actual data you need, you could do this:

```
print(f'{div_text_header}: {div_text_value}')
```

And it appears you're trying to get this for all data. This should work:

```
div_headers = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "col span-3"})
div_values = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "col span-9"})
for header, value in zip(div_headers, div_values):
  print(f'{header.get_text()}: {value.get_text()}')
```

Comment: Name: 1066 Tidsskrift for historie [English]
URL: http://www.universitypress.dk/shop/1066-tidsskrift-for-73c1.html
Country: Denmark
Number of Publications: 1 [view ]
Publications: 
1066 Tidsskrift for Historie

ID: 1939
Date Created: 29 May 2014 09:09:37 UTC
Last Modified: 13 March 2019 11:14:41 UTC
URI: http://v2.sherpa.ac.uk/id/publisher/1939

Comment: It give the above result. there is one link in number of publication : 1 [view] and it link to a webpage after I open that page there is one more webpage. so, How to get the data from one to the last page. so, How to link those data into above script. Is there any way to create multiple soup in one script. or there is some other way to get those result in one csv file

Comment: Glad that it worked for you! Do you mind upvoting my answer and accepting it then? I'm trying to get enough reputation to comment. Thank you!

Comment: As for your second question, you could add a line in the for loop for when there is a link. something like this: `if value.find('a'): new_url = value.find('a).attrs['href']` with that new url you could create a new soup: `newSoup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(new_url).content, 'html.parser')`